# How to join using double LTRIM

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I'm trying to join two tables through specific code, however in primary table
i have to trim some numerical characters ('858','859') in order to correctly join to second table.(ca1)
I need to specifically TRIM just these two numerical characters

[image] "tables"

I have tried several things. Including:

```
JOIN T2 ON (LTRIM(t1.code, '859') AND LTRIM(t1.code, '859') = t2.code
```

resulting in error:

> invalid relational operator

I expected succesfull join with this LTRIM combination, however with no success;

Comment: `JOIN T2 ON  t1.code =  '859'+t2.code`??

Answer (score 2):

`TRIM()` doesn't do what you want.

```
ON (t2.code = t1.code AND SUBSTR(t1.code, 1, 3) NOT IN ('858', '859')) OR
   (t2.code = SUBSTR(t1.code, 4) AND SUBSTR(t1.code, 1, 3) IN ('858', '859'))
```

Or, you can express this as:

```
ON t1.code IN (t2.code, '858' || t1.code, '859' || t2.code)
```

This simpler formulation is not *exactly* the same.  If `t2.code` had both `'8581' and '1'`, then both would match `'8581'` in `t1.code`.  I am guessing this situation doesn't occur in your data.

I should caution you that using `OR` or function calls in `JOIN` conditions can really kill performance.